# How to save Text Input data locally in json format through shared preferences in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am creating app in Flutter in which I need to save data coming from textinput through shared preferences in JSON Format. I searched about JSON serialization in dart before saving it to the shared preferences
I created a Model class for serializing JSON  which is given below :

```dart
class ServerData {
  final String servername;
  final String serverurl;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  ServerData(this.servername, this.serverurl, this.username, this.password);

  ServerData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : servername = json['servername'],
        serverurl = json['serverurl'],
        username = json['username'],
        password = json['password'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'servername' : servername,
    'serverurl' : serverurl,
    'username' : username,
    'password' : password
  };
}
```

Now I need to store the input data with the help of TextEditingController :

```dart
final _servername = TextEditingController();
final _serverurl = TextEditingController();
final _username = TextEditingController();
final _password = TextEditingController();

ServerData serverData = new ServerData(_servername.text,_serverurl.text,_username.text,_password.text); 

/* I am getting error of "Only static members can be accessed in Initializers" in above code */

String encodeData = jsonEncode(serverData); /* Not able to use encode and decode due to error in ServerData object */
```

I need help regarding this.

Comment: You can watch solution, but I don't understand. All of your controllers are just created and empty. So, you are creating `ServerData` with empty strings

Comment: Actually I was trying to store all the textinput in serverdata through textediting controller but I am doing it in wrong because I am initialising it with empty text inputs. So do I need to setState first for all the inputs?

Comment: You have to create `ServerData` in moment when you exactly want to save data. It can by on pressing the button or on changing text in `TextField`

Comment: Yes, I was able to store data now json format Thanks for that. But what if I want to store another Json data in the same key of shared preference and it should look like a list.

Comment: It's not the good practice - store different formats in one list. It would be better to save with different keys. But if you really want - you can put your data to jsonArray and save it, so it will be list

Answer (score 1):

You have to move initialization inside `initState`:

```
ServerData serverData;
String encodeData;

@override
void initState() {
  serverData = new ServerData(_servername.text,_serverurl.text,_username.text,_password.text);
  encodeData = jsonEncode(serverData);
  super.initState();
}
```